# form submit inside bootstrap modal form to do an appendTo html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, appendto

heres the DEMO, Heres the demo ttp://jsfiddle.net/2GfhF/7

form action error? when I try it on localhost, val from from shows in a new row but dissapear afterwards. any sols?

Comment: "http://jsfiddle.net/2GfhF/7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if checked, it equals to text active , if not equals to inactive inside the:

**You can use the code**

```
 if($("#checkbox_status").prop('checked') == true){
    $tr.append($("<td />", {
        text:  'Active'
    }))
    }else{
                $tr.append($("<td />", {
        text:  'Inactive'
    }))
```

Comment: Hi Bhavin, im trying to add a style css and class for the td, but the text doesnt seem to show up, 

  if($("#checkbox_status").prop('checked') == true){
  $tr.append($("<td style='text-align:center;' class='label-success' />", {
    text:  'Active'
  }))
  }else{
        $tr.append($("<td style='text-align:center;' class='label-danger' />", {
    text:  'Inactive'
  }))
  };

Comment: thank you, bhavin, im actually now struggling on how to make the newly added <td> of Edit become editable, Im using a external table_editable.js, i can give you the js if you could help,

Comment: please post another question for that... because it is different purpose

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to add `return false` on **form submit**, because it reload page.

OR you can add following code after `.appendTo()` call

```
$('.form-actions button[type="button"]').trigger('click');//to close modal

    return false;// stop page to reload
```

**New Updated full script**

```
$("#save_add_new_row").click(function () {
    var $tr = $('<tr />');
    $tr.append($("<td />", {
        text: $("#category_selection_list").val()
    }));
    $tr.append($("<td />", {
        text: $("#curriculum_name").val()
    }));
    $tr.append($("<td />", {
        text: $("#curriculum_textarea").val()
    }));
     if($("#checkbox_status").prop('checked') == true){
    $tr.append("<td style='text-align:center;' class='label-success' >Active</td>");
    }else{
        $tr.append("<td style='text-align:center;' class='label-danger' >Inactive</td>");

    }
    //$tr.append($("<td />", { text: $(".test5:checked").val() }))
    $tr.appendTo($("#sample_editable_1"));
$('.form-actions button[type="button"]').trigger('click');//to close modal

    return false;
});
```

Comment: You welcome, you can give up vote, if you would like

Comment: I have add another answer for this question you can use that one

Comment: thanks will upvote, hi about the new <td> <a>edit
here is the textsnip, appreciate if you could help, but thanks anyway.
http://textsnip.com/ghg01c